# Can and how can I embed soundcloud streams in my Android app?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, soundcloud, internet-radio

I'm currently creating a radio player app for a radio station. An extra feature we would like to add is to let the listener listen to recent radio casts via soundcloud. I know this is possible for iOS, but is it also possible for Android?

Can and how can I embed soundcloud streams in my Android app?

Comment: Native app?  Web view?

Comment: Native if possible. Web view shouldn't be a problem at all